How to Add a Timeout Method to DockerPushImageTask in Bamboo PlanSpec?
I'm working with Bamboo PlanSpec and I need to override a native function to add a timeout method. Specifically, I want to modify the DockerPushImageTask class. Here's the original code:
To add a timeout that releases the agent if the Docker push is not successful after 20 minutes, I used a scheduled executor to enforce the timeout
public DockerPushImageTask customRegistryImage(@NotNull String repository) {
    return super.customRegistryImage(repository);
}

@NotNull
@Override
protected DockerRegistryTaskProperties build() {
    return new DockerRegistryTaskProperties(
        description,
        taskEnabled,
        DockerRegistryTaskProperties.OperationType.PUSH,
        image,
        registryType,
        username,
        password,
        email,
        environmentVariables,
        workingSubdirectory,
        requirements,
        conditions,
        sharedCredentialsIdentifier
    );
}

I want to add a timeout method to this class. Is it possible to do this? And using it without problem?
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.task.DockerPushImageTask;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.task.DockerRegistryTaskProperties;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class CustomDockerPushImageTask extends DockerPushImageTask {

    private int timeout;

    public CustomDockerPushImageTask(@NotNull String repository, int timeout) {
        super.customRegistryImage(repository);
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    protected DockerRegistryTaskProperties build() {
        DockerRegistryTaskProperties properties = super.build();
        // Add your timeout logic here
        properties.setTimeout(timeout);
        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<?> future = executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                super.execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                releaseAgent();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });

        try {
            future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            future.cancel(true);
            releaseAgent();
            throw new RuntimeException("Docker push timed out after " + timeout + " minutes", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

    private void releaseAgent() {
        // Logic to release the agent
        System.out.println("Releasing agent due to Docker push failure or timeout.");
        // Add any additional cleanup or release logic here
    }
}

In this example, the execute method uses an ExecutorService to run the Docker push task. The Future.get method is used to wait for the task to complete, with a timeout specified in minutes. If the task times out, the releaseAgent method is called to handle the release of the agent.
Is anyone override the built-in functions?
